# Error en sentencia usanto query()

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy haciendo una consulta interna y quiero obtener un campo (**idperiodo** que es *integer*), solamente debe haber un registro con el campo estado *Activo* por eso uso ***limit 1***. Tengo este código:

```
public function buscar_campo() {
    try {
            $sql = "SELECT idperiodo FROM periodo WHERE estado = 'A' limit 1";

            $BD = new Con();
            $resultado = $BD->query($sql);

            $fila = $resultado->fetchColum();
            $registroVO = new periodoVO();
            $registroVO->setPeriodo( $fila['periodo'] );
            return $registroVO;

        } 
}
```

El error es en la línea `$fila = $resultado->fetchColum();`

Muestra:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   PDOStatement::fetchColum()

Comment: Error de sintaxis, se escribe [`fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php). Además,  esto no crea array asociativo, debes poner el set así: `$registroVO->setPeriodo( $fila);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error de sintaxis: <s>`fetchColum`</s>, en realidad el método es: `fetchColumn`.

Pero lee atentamente [la documentación y los ejemplos](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php), ya que **este método no devuelve un array asociativo de resultados**, por lo tanto aquí vas a tener un *Undefined index*, porque `fetchColum` devuelve el valor de esa columna en limpio:

<s>`$registroVO->setPeriodo( $fila['periodo'] );`</s>

Escribe tu función así:

```
public function buscar_campo() {
    try {
            $sql = "SELECT idperiodo FROM periodo WHERE estado = 'A' limit 1";

            $BD = new Con();
            $resultado = $BD->query($sql);

            $fila = $resultado->fetchColumn();
            $registroVO = new periodoVO();
            $registroVO->setPeriodo( $fila );
            return $registroVO;

        } 

    //Asumo que omitiste el catch por motivos de brevedad
}
```